# How can I get librefblas.a on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, libraries, source-code

For compiling a program I need librefblas.a

Where and how I can obtain this library on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Trusty?

Is there a Ubuntu package that I need to install for get this library?

Comment: No package provides it: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=librefblas.a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Lapack version 3.5.0 with gfortran installed

```
sudo wget http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.5.0.tgz
sudo tar -xzf lapack-3.5.0.tgz
sudo cd lapack-3.5.0
sudo cp INSTALL/make.inc.gfortran make.inc
sudo make blaslib
```

librefblas.a is in directory lapack-3.5.0